# FileVersion in SDK project is correct but is not reflected in output file

Tags: .net, sdk, proj, fileversioninfo

I'm new to the SDK project world and trying to convert an old project over.  It's working great for the most part but I can't get any of the AssemblyInfo.cs info to show up in the output file.  I've deleted the actual assemblyinfo.cs file and placed the version data in the PROJ file and the version data get populated in the Package tab when I build the project.

The problem is that the version data never gets written to the output file.  I don't understand how there could be a disconnect.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

Use the **<Version>** tag instead of **<FileVersion>**.

Something like this:

**<Version>$(RevitVersion).0.0</Version>**

See yaa!